# How to return select options as object from buildSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

According to

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config

value property can be object:

```
If set as object it should be defined as pair value:name - editoptions:{value:{1:'One',2:'Two'}}
```

Json API returns JSON object

```
{"total":2,"page":1,"rows":[
     {"Id":"L-10020","Liik":"10020","Artlnimi":"C vesinikud","Grupp":"L"},
     {"Id":"L-10072","Liik":"10072","Artlnimi":"C D-Perm","Grupp":"L"}
     ... ] }
```

Artlnimi property values should used as select options in search.
I tried to use it to create select list using free jqgrid 4.13.6

```
$grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'Artliik_artlnimi', {
  searchoptions : {
  dataUrl: 'API/ArtliikL',
  buildSelect: function(response){
    var tulem={ '':'All' }, res=JSON.parse(response);
    $.each(res.rows, function(i, item) {
        tulem[item.Artlnimi]=item.Artlnimi;
        }
      );
    return tulem;
    },
  sopt: ['eq']
  },
  stype:"select"
});
```

After that error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'multiple' of undefined
    at Object.success (jquery.jqgrid.src.js:9680)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at done (jquery-1.12.4.js:9840)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.12.4.js:10311)
```

occurs in free jqgrid 4.13.6 source code at line 9680 which contains:

```
 if ($select[0].multiple && $select.find("option[selected]").length === 0 && $select[0].selectedIndex !== -1) {
```

How to fix this so that search element shows data from object returned from buildSelect.
Ifbild select returns string containing select element html it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL `dataUrl` should return HTML fragment with `<select>` and all options. The callback `buildSelect` allows to use `dataUrl`, which returns the information about the options in any other format, but `buildSelect` have to covert the response of `dataUrl` to `<select>` and all options. You can find the following description of `buildSelect` callback in [the old documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) of `editoptions.buildSelect`:

> This option is relevant only if the dataUrl parameter is set. When the
>   server response can not build the select element, you can use your own
>   function to build the select. The function should return a string
>   containing the select and options value(s) as described in dataUrl
>   option. Parameter passed to this function is the server response

The documentation of `searchoptions.buildSelect` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options)) provides practically the same information.

In other words, **you try to use `buildSelect` in the wrong way**. The string, which returns `buildSelect` have to contain HTML fragment of `<select>` and not an as object. Alternatively free jqGrid allows that `buildSelect` returns DOM element of `<select>` with all children options or jQuery wrapper of `<select>`

You can fix your code to something like

```
buildSelect: function (response) {
    var tulem = "<select><option value=''>All</option>";

    $.each(JSON.parse(response).rows, function (i, item) {
        var v = item.Artlnimi;
        // the simplified form of the next statement would be
        //     tulem += "<option value='" + v + "'>" + v + "</option>";
        // but one have to encode/escape the text in more common case.
        tulem += "<option value='" +
            String(v).replace(/\'/g, "&#39;") + "'>" +
            $.jgrid.htmlEncode(v) + "</option>";
    });

    return tulem + "</select>";
}
```

or like

```
buildSelect: function (response) {
    var $tulem = $("<select><option value=''>All</option></select>");

    $.each(JSON.parse(response).rows, function (i, item) {
        $("<option></option>", { value: item.Artlnimi })
            .text(item.Artlnimi)
            .appendTo($tulem);
    });

    return $tulem;
}
```

Comment: This code encodes display value twice: first in `v = $.jgrid.htmlEncode(item.Artlnimi)` and second time using `$.jgrid.htmlEncode(v)` . Is this OK ?